# Go Compilation Error: Declared but not used (Although used)

Tags: go

I have the following Go example:

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    numberOfUsers := 10
    numberOfUsersStr, found := os.LookupEnv("NUMBER_OF_USERS")
    if found {
        numberOfUsers, err := strconv.Atoi(numberOfUsersStr)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("Number of users: %d", numberOfUsers)
}
```

When building this snipper, I get the following error:

```bash
> go build -o app .
.\app.go:14:3: numberOfUsers declared but not used
```

Clearly the variable is used in the last print statement, however it seems hidden from the compiler. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

When using `:=`, you're *declaring a **new** variable*. That means the `numberOfUsers` here:

```
numberOfUsers, err := strconv.Atoi(numberOfUsersStr)
```

is actually shadowing your other `numberOfUsers` variable.

You can fix it by declaring `err` beforehand and then using just `=` instead of `:=` so that you are only assigning a new value to the variable and not declaring a new variable.

```
var err error
numberOfUsers, err = strconv.Atoi(numberOfUsersStr)
```

Comment: If that's the case, I would expect an error like "no new variables on left side of :=".  It's a bit confusing

Comment: @Goplayer you *did* have a new variable on the left side - `err`.

Answer (score 0):

The `numberOfUsers` variable in this line is unused: `numberOfUsers, err := strconv.Atoi(numberOfUsersStr)`.

Here you are redeclaring a new variable `numberOfUsers` in the scope of the `if` statement. This variable is not used in that scope, hence the error.

You probably want something like this:

```golang
func main() {
    numberOfUsers := 10
    numberOfUsersStr, found := os.LookupEnv("NUMBER_OF_USERS")
    if found {
        var err error
        numberOfUsers, err = strconv.Atoi(numberOfUsersStr)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("Number of users: %d", numberOfUsers)
}
```

Notice the difference between `:=` (declare an assign a new variable) and `=` (only assign).

Comment: I see. But isn't the scope inherited inside the if block?

Comment: The variable `numberOfUsers` indeed exists in the `if` block, but here, you are recreating a variable with the same name inside that `if` block (shadowing) because of the `:=`.

Comment: But why the error message isn't something like "no new variables on left side of :=" ?

Comment: Well, there is a new variable on left side (`err`). Anyway, even without this `err`, you'd get the same error. You can always redefine variables even if they already exist. Shadowing is allowed, so an error like "no new variables on left side of :=" would not make sense I guess.